# Is it possible to visit google search by ip addresses?

Tags: vpn, google-search

as we know, google is blocked in china.

I visit google search through VPN. but most of chinese do not have VPN.

I am wondering whether there is a way to visit google search only by ip addresses.
Not all google services, google search only.

any ideas?

Comment: If your network doesn't block, `ping google.com` will give you an IP address that leads to the google main page, but accessing the IP address usually doesn't help circumvent the network ban.